# Best Practice for accurate Clocking of repeated, Synchronous Processes?

Tags: c#, synchronization, state-machine

The greater part of my professional focus is around integrating various hardware to form continuous State Machines for industrial automation. Frequently these applications require a workflow of synchronous actions to be looped, "indefinitely", at a regular and accurate frequencies (<60Hz).

As a self-taught developer, I have employed two techniques to date, neither of which I am convinced are correct:

### 1. Dedicated Thread with Delay

Whether `BackgroundWorker` or equivalent, in pseudo:

1. Define the required `period` as the frequency inverse.
2. Run the process, timed with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` or equivalent.
3. Delay the running Thread by `period - elapsed`. Note: `elapsed` may be inconsistant but always less than `period`.
4. Loop

Reasons I don't like this:

1. Thread Delay... eww.
2. Maintaining timers feels overly managed, and cumbersome.

### 2. System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed

Using the `System.Timers.Timer` class:

1. `Interval` is set to `period` as the frequency inverse.
2. `Elapsed` event handles the process.

Reasons I don't like this:

1. Cross Threading issues frequently arrise
2. Delayed process instances (e.g. due to unexpected data loading or network lag) can result in asynchronous operation.

### Question

Which patterns/methods are considered best practice in these cases? Forgive the verbose detail, I would appreciate considered advise.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with IObservable, and System.Reactive.Linq, you could use Observable.Interval.  It has an overload that accepts an IScheduler parameter too, if you want to implement some custom thread scheduling, but the default thread scheduling works pretty well in most cases.  At the risk of being redundant, Observable.Interval does exactly what you think: continuously invokes the callback delegate on the interval specified by the TimeSpan param.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/60)).Subscribe(_ => {
    // do stuff
});
```